# Labelling pairs of bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add labels to the side of each pair of bars in a chart similar to the one below:

```
library(ggplot2)

treat <- c(rep("Popcorn", 2), rep("Soda", 2), rep("Candy", 2))
eaten <- c(rep(c("Yes", "No"), 3))
persons <- c("20", "41", "12", "78", "37", "62")
risk <- c("1", "1", "0.8", "0.8", "1.15", "1.15")

dfx <- data.frame(treat, eaten, persons, risk)

myplot <- ggplot(data = dfx, aes(x=treat)) +
   geom_bar(aes(y = persons, fill = eaten), stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')   +
  geom_text(y = persons, label = risk)

myplot
```

Bar plot

[image: Bar plot]

However, since the number is supposed to show the risk ratio between the two bars and is the same for both "Yes" and "No", I only need to display one number *just above each pair of bars*, rather than two duplicate numbers on top of each bar.

I tried to set geom_text to only use only the "Yes" value (as in this post: [Label only one bar in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70776812/label-only-one-bar-in-ggplot2)), but I get an error message to add an y-value and when doing so the code doesn't compute.

`geom_text(y = persons, data = dfx[dfx$eaten == "Yes", ], aes(label = risk))`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `aes` to map your variable `y` to the height of the text:

```r
myplot <- ggplot(data = dfx, aes(x=treat)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = persons, fill = eaten), stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')   +
  geom_text(data = dfx[dfx$eaten == "Yes", ], aes(y = persons, label = risk))

myplot
```

[image]

There is a slightly cleaner way to use a subset of your main dataset within an individual geom but I can't remember it right now and Google is letting me down!

Your previous code only worked at all by chance because `persons` existed in the parent environment as well as the data frame `dfx`.