# How to label only one bar in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70776812/label-only-one-bar-in-ggplot2), but I require an answer that is more generalizable. I have the following plot:

```
df <- data.frame(category = c("a", "b", "c"),
                 n = c(1, 2, 3),
                 y = c(0.2, 0.7, 0.9))

category   n     y
       a   1   0.2
       b   2   0.7
       c   3   0.9
```

I create the following plot with `n` on the y-axis:

```
df %>% ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = category, y = n, fill = category), stat = "identity")
```

[image: The plot I get using my data.]

I would like the plot to indicate which `category` has `y` less than `0.5` by inserting a symbol above the respective bar, such as an asterisk `*`. So my desired output would be the following:

[image: My beautiful desired image, which R is making it so difficult to obtain. What a rotten software, why does something so simple have to be a never-ending struggle? Just kill me.]

How do I do this?

Comment: `subset` your data in `geom_text`. i.e. `df %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x = category, y = n, fill = category), stat = "identity") + geom_text(data = subset(df, y < 0.5), aes(x = category, y = n), label = "*")`